# Потоки и CallBack`и

Tags: windows, callback

1. Моё приложение принимает CallBack вызов от стороннего приложения (вызывается CallBack функция), для использования ф-ции обратного вызова, я вызываю функцию (из dll стороннего приложения) SetCallBack(...). Устанавливаю брейкпоинт в Callback и что вижу! - Эта функция вызывается не из основного потока! Почему так происходит? Я же не использую многопоточность? Или второй поток порождается DLL? Я должен синронизировать потоки если пользуюсь результатом CallBack?
2. Если не сложно, объясните как вообще выглядит эта модель взаимодействия двух приложений через CallBack?

Comment: @rejie, синхронизировать, только не потоки, а использование данных в разных потоках, безусловно надо.

Откуда берется другой поток? Либо его порождает функция, которую Вы вызываете для регистрации своего CallBack, либо это обработчик сигнала. В винде, функция f в signal(SIGNUM,f) вызывается в новом потоке.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш callback может быть вызван из любого потока! Скорее всего, клиент и не имеет доступа к вашему "главному" потоку, поэтому вызов из другого потока практически гарантирован.

Синхронизировать нужно не вызовы, а, как правильно заметил [[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), доступ к разделяемым данным. Если есть данные, к которым обращается ваш callback, доступ к ним как в callback'e, так и в остальной части программы, нужно синхронизировать.